# Thread executed only once

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I try to implement this: when app is started I need to create multiple threads that would use the same QDialog window to get messages from user. When thread is started, it asks user for input and if button OK pressed, it prints the message to console. I can't figure out why but I get dialog window only once and after that it prints my one message to console and application finishes.

Here's how I describe dialog window:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QWaitCondition* condition;

    explicit MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void got_message(QString);
public slots:
    void show_message_input();
    void show_message();
private:
    QLabel* message_label;
    QVBoxLayout* vbox;
    QHBoxLayout* hbox;
    QLineEdit* message_input;
    QDialogButtonBox* dialog_buttons;

};

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    setModal(true);

    message_label = new QLabel("Message");
    message_input = new QLineEdit();

    dialog_buttons = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

    hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
    hbox->addWidget(message_label);
    hbox->addWidget(message_input);

    vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
    vbox->addLayout(hbox);
    vbox->addWidget(dialog_buttons);

    setLayout(vbox);

    connect(dialog_buttons, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect(dialog_buttons, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

    condition = new QWaitCondition();
}

void MyDialog::show_message_input()
{
    int result = this->exec();
    if (result == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        emit got_message(message_input->text());
        condition->wakeAll();
    }
}
```

Here's MyThread class:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(int id, MyDialog* window, QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void show_input();
public slots:
    void print_message(QString);
private:
    static QMutex mutex;
    static QMutex mutex2;
    MyDialog* window;
    int id;
    void run();
    void get_captcha_value();
};

QMutex MyThread::mutex;
QMutex MyThread::mutex2;

MyThread::MyThread(int id, MyDialog* window, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    this->id = id;
    this->window = window;

    connect(this, SIGNAL(show_input()), this->window, SLOT(show_message_input()));
}

void MyThread::get_captcha_value()
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    connect(this->window, SIGNAL(got_message(QString)), SLOT(print_message(QString)));
    emit show_input();
    mutex2.lock();
    window->condition->wait(&mutex2);
    mutex2.unlock();
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    mutex.lock();
    qDebug() << "Starting thread " << id;
    mutex.unlock();
    get_captcha_value();
    mutex.lock();
    qDebug() << "Finishing thread " << id;
    mutex.unlock();
}

void MyThread::print_message(QString message)
{
    qDebug() << message;
    QObject::disconnect(this, SLOT(print_message(QString)));
}
```

And `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyDialog* window = new MyDialog();
    QList<MyThread*> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        MyThread* thread = new MyThread(i, window);
        threads << thread;
        thread->start();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Subclassing `QThread` is not a good idea if you're going to use slots. Stated in the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details): *It is important to remember that a QThread object usually lives in the thread where it was created, not in the thread that it manages. This oft-overlooked detail means that a QThread's slots will be executed in the context of its home thread, not in the context of the thread it is managing. For this reason, implementing new slots in a QThread subclass is error-prone and discouraged.*

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is that you're inheriting from QThread. Unless you're wanting to re-write how Qt handles threading, [you're doing it wrong!](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

What you need to do is have a class that inherits from QObject and move the instances to a new thread. The main problem from inheriting QThread is that it can cause confusion about thread affinity (which thread an object is running on).

Also, creating more threads than processor cores is just a waste of resources.

I suggest you [read this article](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) on how to use Qt threading and stop inheriting from QThread.

Finally, the use of QMutex is to protect multiple threads accessing the same data simultaneously. You should be able to remove all of them in the code you've shown. Emitting signals with data from one thread to be received by a slot on another thread is the preferred method in Qt.

Comment: Creating more CPU-bound threads than processor cores will be a waste of resources.

Comment: @MartinJames, well of-course, but it is assumed to be CPU-bound in this case, as all threads in the code are created and running. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: In case I write network application, it wouldn't be cpu-bounded, right?

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov, a thread that is CPU-bound is one which the speed of its execution is tied to the speed of the CPU. In contrast, something that is IO-bound is not tied to the CPU; for example, waiting for user input where the thread spends most of its time waiting on the user.

Comment: What did you mean in your final suggestion? I have one window and I don't want threads to access it the simultaneously. That's why I use mutex. What is wrong with that? Tried to apply this thing from article, now it's pretty much the same but the thread doesn't get any signal from window.

Comment: If you're still getting a problem, having changed your code to inherit from QObject, instead of QThread, please post that code. As for using QMutex to stop multiple threads from accessing the window, you're going about it the wrong way. Have each object send a message to a controlling object on the main thread. This controlling object can then update the window.